# Can I tell where an included PHP file has been referenced from?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress has many useful functions to find out what the current page you're looking at is, but is there any way to find out from which template file another file has been included *from*?

For example:

Within my theme, I'm using several page templates. I have a PHP file containing a block that I want to display in various places around the site, including different page templates **AND the sidebar**.

I need to make slightly different calls to `wpdb->get_results` based on what page I'm on, but I also want to give a different query when this PHP file is included within `sidebar.php`.

So far, the block in the sidebar, is only following the `else` part of the below statement, and using `get_template_part('sidebar.php')` does not work.

```
if( is_page_template('template-procedure.php') ) {
    $beforeAfters = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE procedureID = '.$post->ID.' AND procedure_display = 1 ORDER BY ID DESC');
} elseif( is_page_template('template-patient-story.php') ) {
    $beforeAfters = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE patientID = '.$post->ID.' AND patient_display = 1 ORDER BY set_order ASC');
} elseif( is_page_template('sidebar.php') ) {
    $beforeAfters = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM wp_before_after WHERE procedureID = 238 AND sidebar_display = 1 ORDER BY RAND()');
}
```

How can I target the sidebar file, whilst also using page templates?

Comment: Have you tried get_included_files method?

Comment: In which context will that function help me?

Comment: You are not using PDO and namespaces? You can create a log entry / silent warning in the file that is included.

Comment: Again, how will this help me? I want to replace `is_page_template('sidebar.php')` with something that will return TRUE when featured within the sidebar file

Comment: A couple of notes, unrelated to your question, but which may be useful anyway: (1) If it's possible for `$post->ID` to be a string, then your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection attack. You should make sure you've sanitised this input. (2) Using `ORDER BY RAND()` is fine as long as your DB table is small. If you have a lot of data, it may become unusably slow, as it requires a complete re-read of the entire table every time it is called. If you think this may be a problem, there are alternative ways of getting random order which have much better performance.

Comment: Thanks @Simba, I have replaced the `RAND()` with ID. The tables have the potential to get quite large, although nothing over 500 records, not sure if that constitutes as small?. `$post->ID` will always be an integer, as it's a Wordpress object

Comment: Re "what constitutes as small?" I routinely deal with DBs with millions of rows, so 500 records is fairly small. My general rule of thumb is to avoid `RAND()` on tables that will go over a few hundred records, so 500 rows is right at the top end of what I'd consider using it for. But the real question is how does it impact your system's performance? Even at this size, rand() will have an effect, particularly under load with multiple simultaneous visitors. At this size, you could still consider keeping rand() if you cache the results so it isn't called every time.

Comment: Would it not be possible to adapt the is template function to return custom values that you can use for further customizations or write a wrapper around is template function like a custom loader. The options are very limited if you cannot adapt the source code, one of the reasons i dont use wordpress. Else you will need to write a plugin that mimics the function is page template. Just brainstorming.